# Weblogic breaks CXF certificate authentication when using proxy

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic, cxf

I've got a CXF client configured in code. It uses certificate authentication to the WS server and proxy settings(which is without authentication). Everything works perfectly fine from the unit test and on Tomcat, but breaks when deployed on Weblogic. It goes through the proxy, but doesn't authenticate with the certificate. The strange thing is, that if I'm not going throught the proxy, the certificate authentication works. What can be the problem?

The code I'm using for initializing the client:

```
 JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setEndpointName(SERVICE_NAME);
factory.setAddress("Address of the WS server");
factory.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
this.port = (MyService) factory.create();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

//proxy settings
HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setProxyServer("IP OF THE PROXY");
policy.setProxyServerPort("PORT OF THE PROXY");
conduit.setClient(policy);        

//TLS
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ARCHIVE_FILE_FORMAT);
keyFile = getKeyFileUrl().openStream();
keyStore.load(keyFile, getPassword().toCharArray());
KeyManager[] myKeyManagers = getKeyManagers(keyStore, getPassword());
TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsCP.setKeyManagers(myKeyManagers);
tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
FiltersType cipherSuiteFilter = new FiltersType();
cipherSuiteFilter.getInclude().add(SSL_RSA_WITH_3_DES_EDE_CBC_SHA);
cipherSuiteFilter.getExclude().add(DH_ANON);
tlsCP.setCipherSuitesFilter(cipherSuiteFilter);
conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```

When I enabled SSL debugging, I'm getting tyhese messages in the log file:

```
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133523> <BEA-000000> <weblogic user specified trustmanager validation status 0> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133523> <BEA-000000> <SSLTrustValidator returns: 0> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133523> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: No trust failure, validateErr=0.> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133524> <BEA-000000> <Performing hostname validation checks: www.cfmu.eurocontrol.int> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133524> <BEA-000000> <Proxying through 85.125.226.9> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133525> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Successfully completed post-handshake processing.> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133526> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 230 bytesProduced = 261.> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133528> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 1729 bytesProduced = 1786.> 
####<Oct 2, 2013 4:08:53 PM UTC> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <lmdesetup-jab> <fwf-acg> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1380730133627> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads]]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 733 bytesProduced = 705.>
```

What does status=OK mean? Do I have ssl connection? Then why the server sends the response as if not using certificate.

I have tried different versions of CXF(including latest 2.7.7) and different versions of weblogic.

Comment: Are you using the DemoTrust certs? Looks like it based on that message. Also you can try and add -Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true and -Dssl.debug=true to your server startup script to get more info.

Comment: Yes. But I think the problem is not in the certificates. It works if I don't use proxy.

Comment: I've added the SSL debuggin output. (not all of it, because there are tons of it. Only the part immediately after request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the Oracle documentation, it seems Weblogic Server rejects any certificates in a certificate chain that do not have the basic constraint extension defined as CA. You can use the command line argument:

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enforceConstraints=option
```

Where option can be 'strong' or 'true', strict, or off. Look at the documentation:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/secmanage/ssl.html#wp1194346
```

Have you set this flag?

```
What worked:
```

Start your weblogic server. Go to 'Servers' under 'Environment'. Click on the server name. Under the 'General' tab, set the ClientCertProxyEnabled flag to true.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all possible settings, but it didn't have any effect. I've also tried ```-Dweblogic.security.SSL.nojce=true```, but that didn't help either. I'm stuck on this stupid problem for two weeks. I just can't understand why does it work on Tomcat and not on Weblogic. How can i tell if the certificate has "constraint extension defined in CA"? I've got SSL debugging on and I can see a lot of output, but I don't kknow what to look for.

Comment: In this forum, https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2265305, the log messages, look just like yours. I am not an expert on security, but they have some configuration for renegotiation, which apparently is not documented in Oracle manual.. may be you could try that. This is just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: Check this out too: http://<your_weblogic_hostname>:port/consolehelp/console-help.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=page&helpId=Corecoreserverserverconfiggeneraltitle#core.server.serverconfiggeneral.clientcertproxyenabled.label. Maybe you have already done it, but you do have to set the ClientCetProxyEnabled flag to true. Hope that helps.

Comment: user1807337: Cool man. Your link didn't work, but "clientcertproxyenabled" was the right keyword. Could you edit your answer so that I can give you the bounty.

Comment: Great! I am glad it worked. Well I should have mentioned that you should replace <your_weblogic_hostname> with the IP address of your weblogic server and the port with the actual port number. That is the reason the link did not work. Of course, the weblogic server had to be started! I will add a new answer so you can mark it right.

Comment: Of course I did that :). But the server didn't gave me any result. Maybe I was not logged in or something. Anyway it works now and the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same kind of problem a while ago (CXF, mutual SSL authentication, proxy server,weblogic) , i patched the CXF client to apply a (temporary) workaround ( http://pastebin.com/VfKA7MRC ) , because it's a bug in the weblogic code since 10.3 in the method weblogic.net.https.HttpsClient.openServer() when using a proxy . Maybe the problem is already fixed now i didn't look into it for 1,5 year